# K8s nodeport service forwards traffic to unready pod

Tags: kubernetes, kind

So far I thought I had a good understanding of Kubernetes. Today I was startled to see a service forwarding traffic to an unready pod. Can somebody fill this knowledge gap for me? Here is what I'm doing:

I'm using the latest version of [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) to spin up a Kubernetes cluster (Version: 1.25).
On the cluster I'm running a deployment configured to run 3 replicas of a pod running a HTTP server. Next to it is a Service of type NodePort forwarding traffic to the 3 pods.
I have configured Kind for use with NodePort services and it works, meaning I can access the web server from outside the cluster.

One of my HTTP requests deliberately crashes a process in one of the pods resuting in this pod's readiness probe to fail while the pod keeps running.

- I can see the status of the pod becoming unready.
- When describing the service, I can see that the unready pod was removed from the list of endpoints of that service.

BUT: Making a request to the node port, I get a response from the unready port. Why? I was expecting the service to forward requests only to ready pods...

I have tried using port-forwarding to the same service. Same result. Is this expected bevaviour of services of type node port?

I can paste my manifest as a bunch of yaml blobs but maybe this is aready clear to someone out there?

Thanks!